# How to show 3 images placed next to each other in jCarousel Lite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am trying to put 3 images next to each other in jCarousel Lite. The 3 images need to be visible and the scroll is set to 2,5.

Here's what it looks like as of now.

[image: example slider view (wrong)]

#### jCarousel Lite

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jcarousel/jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jcarousel/jcarousel.lite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            $(".slideshow").jCarouselLite({
                    btnNext: ".navNext",
                    btnPrev: ".navPrevious",
                    auto: 4000,
                    speed: 6000,
                    visible: 3,
                    scroll: 2.5,
                    circular: true
            });
    });
    </script>
```

#### CSS

```
    .fullSlider {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        width: 1000px;
    }
    .slideshow {
        height:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .slide-prev, .slide-next {
        width:88px;
        height:176px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
    }
    .navPrevious, .navNext {
        background:url("/js/jcarousel/tango/slide_btn.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
        position:absolute;
        width:88px;
        height:176px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        font-size:1px;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        z-index: 1001 !important;
    }
    .navPrevious:hover, .navNext:hover {
        border:none;
    }
    .navPrevious {
        left:5px;
    }
    .navNext {
        right:5px;
    }
    .navNext {
        background-position:-88px 0;
    }
    #slider {
        width:800px;
        height:176px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #slider ul {
        width:800px;
        height:176px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
    }
    #slider ul li {
        width:300px;
        height:176px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0 1px;
        float:left;
    }
    #slider ul li a {
        width:300px;
        height:176px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
    }
    .slide-afb {
        width:300px;
        height:132px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .slide-afb table {
        width:300px;
        height:132px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
    }
    .slide-afb table tr td {
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .slide-afb img {
        width:300px;
        height:132px;
        float:left;
    }
    .slide-tekst {
        width:300px;
        height:44px;
        line-height:44px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        font-size:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

This how I would like it to be:

[image]

I would be thankful if someone could help me with this.

I don’t need the exact answer. If you could let me know what I did wrong or if you could provide some tips or direction then I’ll try to fix this myself.